# SwipeListView in Xamarin Form

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am working on android application using xamarin forms. We have a list that is displaying items. Client want to delete the item on swipe, "left to right" vice versa  . I have a link that is working for xamarin android that i am share with you [Click here](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/android-swipelistview) . I need same thing for Xamarin form. If anybody have any idea please share with me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the Xamarin Forms support only a specific set of [gestures](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/gestures/). 
Those are Pan, Tap and Pich. It does not support Swipe.

You can go and create these events in your native projects and expose via a Renderer.

Or you can use the [MR.Gestures](http://www.mrgestures.com/) which has all the events you need.

The [XLabs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs) project has gestures, which you can use. More discussion about it can be found in this [forum thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27323/how-can-i-recognize-long-press-gesture-in-xamarin-forms).

This a good tutorial - [Gesture Recognizers with Xamarin.Forms](http://arteksoftware.com/gesture-recognizers-with-xamarin-forms/) you can look into if you are trying to build your own gesture recognizes.

There is 2 good solutions provided to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972404/xamarin-forms-swipe-left-swipe-right-gestures) SO Question - [Xamarin Forms Swipe Left/Swipe Right Gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972404/xamarin-forms-swipe-left-swipe-right-gestures).

Comment: Thank you, I am also following Gestures, I was thinking if there is any plugin that can make our life easier.

Comment: Rohit, there is a possibility with gestures, we can swipe the items, but this is tedious task. I am stuck with that.

Comment: yes, but I am working for client. Client don't want to use any paid plugin. So that i am looking for alternate.

Comment: You can try the XLabs one, I have updated my answer to include the same.