# xamarin forms swipe left/right inside grid that is in scrollview

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms and am trying to utilize swipe left and right for some paging.  I found this link [Xamarin Forms Swipe Left/Swipe Right Gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972404/xamarin-forms-swipe-left-swipe-right-gestures) and it had code to do this, but I ran into one problem with iOS.

Since I have a Grid inside of a ScrollView that I let scroll up and down with your finger, when I implement a PanGestureRecognizer for the grid inside the ScrollView, for iOS, the ScrollView no longer scrolls up and down.  Android works fine.

Maybe the PanGestureRecognizer is not the way to go, but it is so close, I wondered if there were a way to bubble up the gesture so the ScrollView when running under iOS would function like android does.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not elegant, but for iOS only, I controlled the scrolling manually in the PanUpdated event of the PanGestureRecognizer.  Hopefully this will get identified as a bug and the workaround code can get removed later.