# Xamarin: PanGestureRecognizer inside Scrollview (Android)

Tags: android, xamarin, scrollview

I've trouble to get the following to work: I have a horizontal scrollview in which a grid is placed. I want the grid to receive pan gestures.

MY XAML:

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Grid RowSpacing="3" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Red" Padding="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Image Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="party.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"></Image>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="AUSGEHEN" TextColor="#646464" />

                    <Image Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="sep.png" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" WidthRequest="1" HeightRequest="10"></Image>

                    <Image Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="contacts.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"></Image>
                    <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="KONTAKTE" TextColor="#646464" />

                    <Image Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="sep.png" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="3" WidthRequest="1" HeightRequest="10"></Image>

                    <Image Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="sports.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4"  WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"></Image>
                    <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Text="SPORT" TextColor="#646464" />

                    <Image Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="sep.png" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="5" WidthRequest="1" HeightRequest="10"></Image>

                    <Image Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="dating.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6"  WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"></Image>
                    <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6" Text="DATING" TextColor="#646464" />

                    <Image Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="sep.png" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="7" WidthRequest="1" HeightRequest="10"></Image>

                    <Image Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="culture.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="8"  WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"></Image>
                    <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="8" Text="KULTUR" TextColor="#646464" />

                    <Image Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="sep.png" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="9" WidthRequest="1" HeightRequest="10"></Image>

                    <Image Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="food.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="10"  WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"></Image>
                    <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="10" Text="ESSEN" TextColor="#646464" />
                    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="OnPanUpdated" />
                    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollView>
```

The problem is that the scrollview "swallows" the vertical swipe gestures. This means that "OnPanUpdated" is not called when the scrollview is horizontally scrolled. If I swipe up/down carefully without moving the scrollview horizontally, "OnPanUpdated" is called.

What I am basically trying to achieve is that if I swipe up or down on my grid inside the scrollview the "OnPunUpdated" should be called. If I swipe horizontally, I want the scrollview to normally scroll horizontally. I wouldn't care if both are called as long as "OnPunUpdated" is called as soon as I swipe over it.

I tried several custom renderers for Android but no luck.

I would be very grateful if someone found some time to help me solve my issue.

NOTE: Only tested on Android.

Comment: When you swipe horizontally, you need the scrollview to normally scroll and the `OnPunUpdated` can be called at the same time?

Comment: Why did you need to implement this feature? Please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Hey, yes, there's a horizontal scrollview and I want to swipe it up with a pan gesture. Think of a simple swipe up bar containing a scroll view. I changed my code a little bit: I Put a transparent boxview above the scrollview, so swiping up works now. But now I can't trigger the scrollview anymore since there's a transparent boxview (containing the PanGestureRecognizer) above it. I thought of inputTransparent=true when a horizontal swipe is detected, but the delay just doesn't feel natural. So, when a user swipes left or right the scrollview should be triggered and when up or down the slide

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> there's a horizontal scrollview and I want to swipe it up with a pan gesture. when a user swipes left or right the scrollview should be triggered and when up or down the slide

You could [create a Pan Container](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/pan/#Creating_a_Pan_Container) and place your `ScrollView` inside this `Container`:

```
public class PanContainer : ContentView
{
    double x, y;

    public PanContainer()
    {
        // Set PanGestureRecognizer.TouchPoints to control the 
        // number of touch points needed to pan
        var panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        panGesture.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);
    }

    void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.StatusType)
        {

            case GestureStatus.Running:
                // Translate and ensure we don't pan beyond the wrapped user interface element bounds.
                Content.TranslationX = Math.Max(Math.Min(0, x + e.TotalX), -Math.Abs(Content.Width - App.ScreenWidth));
                Content.TranslationY = Math.Max(Math.Min(0, y + e.TotalY), -Math.Abs(Content.Height - App.ScreenHeight));
                break;

            case GestureStatus.Completed:
                // Store the translation applied during the pan
                x = Content.TranslationX;
                y = Content.TranslationY;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

In your `.xaml`:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <local:PanContainer>
        <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
            ...

        </ScrollView>
    </local:PanContainer>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56b1s.gif).

Comment: Hi,thanks for your input! However, my main goal is to capture swipes ON the scrollview. That doesn't seem to work in your example. In your example, I can only scroll through the scrollview OR swipe outside of it. I want it to slide up when I swipe my finger across the scrollview (vertical). Is there a way I could detect whether I swipe horizontal or vertical and handle the swipe accordingly (scroll through scrollview when horizontal and slide up the container when I swipe vertically). Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @user2669261, sorry for late, you could refer to: [Xamarin Forms Swipe Left/Swipe Right Gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972404/xamarin-forms-swipe-left-swipe-right-gestures).