# Scrollable StackLayout without ScrollView

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, scrollview, gesture

I have a problem with ScrollView. It does not work with swipe and pan gestures on Android ([proof 1](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/44154/panning-can-work-on-a-scrollview-on-ios-and-uwp-bu.html), [proof 2](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1977)). I am thinking of creating a scrollable StackLayout but I don't know how to create.
Help me please.
Or are there other solutions how to make both a vertical scroll and a swipe left and right?

Comment: why do you need a swipe left right?

Comment: @G.hakim Swipe right needed to go back. Swipe left is needed to follow the link

Comment: @hope this helps. https://github.com/markolazic88/SwipeCardView

Comment: Maybe you'll just add a swipe gesture to your stacklayout

Comment: @LeoZhu this does not work. ScrollView intercepts scrolling

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54480748/6589692