# behavioral differences between swipe gesture on android and iOS when using a scrollview

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, swipe-gesture

There seems to be some behavioral differences between attaching a swipe gesture on android and iOS. The actual gesture recognizer is attached to a stacklayout, which is the parent of a number of other views. One of those views is a scrollview, which I suspect to be the problem. Swiping on the scrollview works on iOS, but not on android.

I have no clue as to how to work around this problem as it seems to be a bug in Xamarin.forms. Has anyone encountered and managed to fix this problem?

Comment: Found answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54480748/8288212, which worked great!

Comment: Hi, you can update it in answer and mark it  :)

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I'm sorry, how do I do that?

Comment: Refer to this .https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers If let me answer , I will answer by your link. Then can mark and vote it.